# Worksheet Name in Variable Includes Filepath

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I am storing a worksheet name in a variable.  When I use that variable to create a hyperlink, the resulting link includes the filepath, which I do not want, I only want the worksheet name.  Any help greatly appreciated.

```
Dim wsname as string

wsname = ActiveSheet.Name  ' at this point wsname = "sheetname"

ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:=wsname, SubAddress:= _
        "", TextToDisplay:="Tasks"
```

Link is created as `"C:\\.....\filename\\"sheetname"`

I have also tried declaring wsname as Worksheet (Dim wsname As Worksheet).

Comment: Think a hyperlink must be to a cell, not a worksheet, and you need to use `SubAddress`. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `hyperlink` function instead. Adding `#` in the formula will create a link to the sheet without file path.

```
Selection.Cells = "=HYPERLINK(""#" & wsname & "!A1"",""Tasks"")"
```

Comment: Thanks!  Exactly what I was looking for!  (Wasn't aware of the #).

Answer (score 0):

### Hyperlink to (a Cell in) Another Worksheet

- The first example creates a hyperlink in the first cell of the `Selection` (if it is a range) linking to cell `A1` in the same worksheet.
- The second example creates a hyperlink in the first cell of the `Selection` (if it is a range) linking to cell `A1` in `Sheet2` of the same workbook (`ActiveWorkbook`).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub addHyperlink()
        
    Const dAddress As String = "A1"
        
    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        
        Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = ActiveSheet
        Dim sCell As Range: Set sCell = Selection.Cells(1)
   
        sws.Hyperlinks.Add _
            Anchor:=sCell, _
            Address:="", _
            SubAddress:="'" & sws.Name & "'!" & dAddress, _
            TextToDisplay:="Tasks"
    
    End If

End Sub

Sub addHyperlink2()
        
    Const dName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dAddress As String = "A1"
        
    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        
        Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = ActiveSheet
        Dim sCell As Range: Set sCell = Selection.Cells(1)
        
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = sws.Parent.Worksheets(dName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If Not dws Is Nothing Then
            sws.Hyperlinks.Add _
                Anchor:=sCell, _
                Address:="", _
                SubAddress:="'" & dws.Name & "'!" & dAddress, _
                TextToDisplay:="Tasks"
        Else
            MsgBox "The worksheet '" & dName & "' does not exist.", _
                vbCritical, "Add Hyperlink"
        End If
    
    Else
    
        MsgBox "The current selection is not a range.", _
            vbCritical, "Add Hyperlink"
    
    End If

End Sub
```